How to get the global position of a link in Gazebo Sim
I am trying to get the position of a specific link on my robot that I am simulating in Gazebo (Harmonic) in reference to the world frame. Based on what I have read this has been previously possible with subscribing to the gazebo/LinkStates topic but I don't know what would be the alternative in this new version of Gazebo. I have been trying to use the Odometry plugin (https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/classgz_1_1sim_1_1systems_1_1OdometryPublisher.html) in my URDF-file but I am only able to get the position of the base link and I don't throughly understand what I should put inside the tags. Any advice?
